# Facing issue during insert date in oracle database using PHP form

Tags: php, oracle

i am facing issue during insert date in oracle database from PHP form.

Below is insert query...

```
$sql_insert = oci_parse($conn, 'insert into auto_debit_data_insert (req_id,req_type,scheduled_date) values (req_id_seq.nextval,:service_type,:sdate)');
$data6 = $_POST['sdate'];
oci_bind_by_name($sql_insert, ':sdate', $data6);
$result=oci_execute($sql_insert);
```

below is the form of PHP where i post the date field.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sdate">Scheduled Date:</label>
<div class="col-sm-5" style="width:200px">
   <input type="date" class="form-control" id="sdate" name="sdate" required>
</div>
```

can anyone help me to fix this. i want to insert only date(YYYY-DD-MM) format in scheduled_date column.

Comment: You have two bind variables `:service_type` and `:sdate` but you only appear to be binding one value.

Comment: sorry to mention another bind variable...
oci_bind_by_name($sql_insert, ':service_type', $data1);

Comment: actually i am facing issue on date field.....can you please help me to solve it..

Comment: What is the "issue"? Can you edit your question to contain the error message (and the code you are actually using).

Comment: i am using php form where type=date. i am using this to insert a date field in oracle table...

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a string and use the `TO_DATE()` function within Oracle:

```
$sql_insert = oci_parse(
  $conn,
  "insert into auto_debit_data_insert (req_id,req_type,scheduled_date) values (req_id_seq.nextval,:service_type,TO_DATE(:sdate,'YYYY-DD-MM'))"
);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'YYYY' (T_STRING) in
getting this error

Comment: Have you changed the quotes surrounding the query string from `'` to `"`? Otherwise the single quotes surrounding the date format mask in the query will terminate the PHP string.

Comment: You can't use `"YYYY-DD-MM"` in the query as Oracle only supports `'` for surrounding string literals. You will need to use `"` for the PHP string and `'` for the embedded oracle format mask string (or else escape the single quotes embedded in the string).